# How do I delete an Eclipse perspective for a plugin I uninstalled?

Tags: eclipse

I was evaluating the Enterprise IDE plugin for Eclipse, and ultimately decided not to purchase it.  After I uninstalled the plugin, I was left with a bunch of perspective buttons (the ones in the far upper-right-hand corner) which I can't remove.  How do I get rid of the manually, without nuking my workspace?

**Edit**: To be clear, right-clicking and going to "close" does nothing.  Not even an error message.

Comment: So just right-clicking and choosing close doesn't work?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How did you uninstall that plugin ?

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299199/anonymous-coward) details in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494054/6309), `Help-> Install new software` -> click on `"Whats already installed?"` is the right way to uninstall a plugin, and should get rid of the perspective as well.

If the plugin was installed in the `dropins` directory or in `<eclipse>/plugins` and `<eclipse>/features`, did you delete all `directories/jar` in `<eclipse>/features`, because if that plugin was packaged as a product, it did define in the [product extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_def_extpt.htm) a [plugin_customization.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708502/eclipse-rcp-how-to-order-perspective-buttons-belonging-to-different-plugins/708547#708547) which can indicate some perspective buttons.

If not, the only solution is to have a careful look at your workspace metadata, look for all recent file related to that plugin and remove them.
Make a copy of your workspace first though.

As an example of such a careful look at your workspace metadata", [user900975](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900975/user900975) points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110633/6309) the **`<your workspace folder>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml`** file, with `<perspectives>` element and `<perspective>` child elements that you can remove.

---

Note: [Eightball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187715/eightball) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1548470/6309) (upvoted) the possibility to list and delete a perspective.

[image: delete perspective]

Since he mentions "Some of them are un-removable. I don,t know why", my original answer above still stands.

---

[Alexandros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309816/alexandros) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892203/how-do-i-delete-an-eclipse-perspective-for-a-plugin-i-uninstalled/892258#comment84910567_892258):

> This helped me fix this, but in my case the file I had to edit while Eclipse was closed was:
>
> ```
> .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi
> ```

Comment: This helped me fix this but in my case the file I had to edit while Eclipse was closed was ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi"

Comment: @Alexandros Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 69):

Click `Window ► Preferences ► General ► Perspectives`. Select the perspective you want to delete and remove it. Some of them are unremovable. I don't know why.

Comment: It seems built-in perspectives cannot be deleted.

Comment: Those still offered by installed plug-ins aren't removable, no.

Answer (score 8):

I was suffering the same problem with a left-over perspective button for SVN repository Exploring. It wouldn't disappear using the close option. However it did disappear after selecting from Window -> Close All Perspectives.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

<your workspace folder>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml contains a <perspectives> element with <perspective> child elements.  You can delete <perspective> elements and they will no longer appear in the toolbar.  Eclipse writes to this file when it exits so your changes will be overwritten if you don't quit Eclipse first.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed a plugin, click `Help ► Install new software`, then click `What's already installed?` in the bottom right. Uninstall what you want, the perspective will be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try launching Eclipse with the `-clean` command line argument. This cleans out the Eclipse runtime cache, so it might fix your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing a plugin.  The answer is quite simple, if not obvious.

1. Open Window | Preferences
2. Click General node
3. Click Perspectives

Find the perspective in the list and then select Delete command on the right.

The list will refresh and your perspective is deleted.

Comment: This worked for for one case, but of another the delete button was disabled. The problematic one was the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective.