# How to create a custom PerspectiveBar in RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In my application, when I call `getWindowConfigurer().setShowPerspectiveBar(true);` the application will show a default PerspectiveBar look like this

[image]

Now I want to customize my PerspectiveBar by remove the small icon at the left and add few more button.

How can I do that?

Comment: By 'more buttons' do you mean more perspectives shown by default? Removing the icons would be very difficult.

Comment: Could you please tell me the way to edit or change the PerspectiveBar. Or is there a way to create our Perspectivebar?

Comment: Replacing the perspective bar is pretty much impossible since all the classes are in **internal** packages which are not part of the Eclipse API. This [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/708502/2670892) cover some of the things that can be done.